# Google Map Autocomplete remove blank space and insert plus(+) inside address string

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi everyone I have google map Address autocomplete searchbox on my page. When I press Enter then my

Url is coming like this:
http://localhost/realestate-site/public/property_home?address=Birmingham AL

instead of this I want my url should look like this I want to insert plus sign in place of Blank space
http://localhost/realestate-site/public/property_home?address=Birmingham+AL

Script:

```
predictionsDropDown.empty();
   $.each(predictions, function(i, prediction) {
     predictionsDropDown.append('<div>' +    $.fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate(prediction.terms[0].value) + '</div'   +'<div>&nbsp;'+ $.fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate(prediction.terms[1].value) + '</div');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a string replace function should answer your need. Either the Javascript or the PHP replace function should do that.

Javascript

```
string.replace(“ “,”+”)
```

PHP

```
str_replace(" ","+","string");
```